# To pull last friday date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query to pull the last friday date with given a date. It works for all day except if the given date is today.

> select dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) %
>   7), getdate())

Taking for example, today is 2014-02-14. if i apply to the query above, the result returned is still 2014-02-14

> dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, '2014-02-14') + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7),
>   '2014-02-14')

If i put as 2014-02-13 below, then it returned last friday date properly.

> select dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, '2014-02-13') + 1 +
>   @@DATEFIRST) % 7), '2014-02-13')

Can you help how i can i get last Friday date if given today is Friday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check to see if the current day is Friday with `DATENAME` and if so, just subtract 7 days, otherwise, use the function you made

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' THEN
        CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    ELSE
        DATEADD(d, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), GETDATE())
    END AS 'LastFriday'
```

Comment: What if language settings aren't English? Also, using [string literals as column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) has been deprecated. This should be avoided in any new code.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  Like many in the comments of it, I have always done AS vs =.  That will be quite the hard habit to break.

Comment: No problem, I think `alias = column` as opposed to `column AS alias` is entirely personal preference, and I would never try and force anyone to use one over the other, but it is the clearest article I could find that confirms that `column AS 'alias'` is deprecated. It is someway down the page on the [deprecated list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), so wouldn't have been immediately clear why I had linked it.

Answer (score 3):

How about a brute force approach:

```
select dateadd(day,
               (case when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Friday' then -7
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Saturday' then -1
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Sunday' then -2
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Monday' then -3
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Tuesday' then -4
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Wednesday' then -5
                     when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Thursday' then -6
                end),
               cast(getdate() as date)
              );
```

This does the logic for today.  You can replace all the `getdate()` references with another date for another date.

Answer (score 3):

Your first attempt seems pretty close, I think you just need to move the 1 to outside of the modulo function. This works for me:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -1 - ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

Then tested on a larger sample it still seems to work:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (DateFirst INT, Date DATE, LastFriday DATE)
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE @I < 8
    BEGIN

        SET DATEFIRST @i;

        WITH TestDates AS
        (   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -Number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
            FROM    master..spt_values 
            WHERE   Type = 'P'
            AND     Number BETWEEN 0 AND 20
        )
        INSERT @T (DateFirst, Date, lastFriday)
        SELECT  @I,
                Date,
                LastFriday = DATEADD(DAY, -1 - ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), Date)
        FROM    TestDates;

        SET @i += 1;

    END

SELECT  *
FROM    @T
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(LastFriday) 
            FOR DateFirst IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
        ) pvt
ORDER BY Date;
```

This works for all language and datefirst settings.

If you can control your datefirst settings this becomes simpler:

```
SET DATEFIRST 6;
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

However I would always recommend making your queries safe against local settings.